# What is the cause for the "resource unavailable" recurrent issue?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers, limit

The issue affects not only Docker, but sometimes the whole system.

##### Issue 1

Sometimes when accessing the remote server I am unable to execute commands on the terminal and receive the error `-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable` multiple times for simple commands such as `cd`, `ls`, and others. After some time the issue is gone, and later it comes back.

##### Issue 2

Another issue which I think is also part of the bigger issue is that sometimes I can't manage Docker properly, when I execute commands such as `docker ps`, `docker images` and others I receive the error `runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

##### Issue 3

Somethimes when I try to build a Docker image, at the start or during the build process in some step, the build fails also with the error `runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

The remote server runs on **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS**.

#### RAM Memory

Running `free -m` I get the information about RAM in MB:

```
                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            32768        3333       24768         133        4665       29300
Swap:               0           0           0
```

#### CPU

Running `lscpu` I get the information about the CPUs:

```
Architektur:             x86_64
CPU Operationsmodus:     32-bit, 64-bit
Byte-Reihenfolge:        Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
Liste der Online-CPU(s): 0-7
Thread(s) pro Kern:      1
Kern(e) pro Socket:      8
Sockel:                  1
Anbieterkennung:         AuthenticAMD
Prozessorfamilie:        25
Modell:                  1
Modellname:              AMD EPYC 7453 28-Core Processor
Stepping:                1
CPU MHz:                 1999.725
BogoMIPS:                5489.89
Virtualisierung:         AMD-V
Hypervisor-Anbieter:     Parallels
Virtualisierungstyp:     Container
```

#### Docker

Docker version: `Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc`

Docker compose version: `Docker Compose version v2.21.0`

#### Limits

Running `ulimit -a` I get the following:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 4124817
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 262144
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 32768
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The open files number was increased from 1024 to 32768 and the max locked memory was increased from 65536 to 262144. The issue still persists after the increasing.

I have increased those numbers by editing the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file which now contains:

```
x_project       soft nofile   32768
x_project       -    memlock  262144
root            soft nofile   32768
root            -    memlock  262144
```

I had to edit this file because setting the limits with the `ulimit` command wasn't persisting the changes.

The `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory is empty.

#### cAdvisor observation

A container running [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) was set on the remote server in order to monitor the system's resources' usage by the containers.

When the Issue 1 was ocurring in the server and sunddenly stopped I opened the cAdvisor to see what happened and could check the system's memory usage by the containers:

[Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFR7a.png)

Between 2:07:45 and 2:08:00 is possible to see that the cyan line decreases. That was the moment in which the issue 1 stopped.

#### Current situation

There are 24 containers running in the server. They are built with docker compose. The docker compose files doesn't set any memory/CPU limit to the containers. They all seem to work fine. But I'm unable to start/build new containers.

To demonstrate it, those are the results for trying to run `docker run hello-world`:

```
root@h2877818:~# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: ttrpc: closed: unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container:

root@h2877818:~# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/724798e971a7ba8d31d6f3f1b900d01152efee06a64adedad7c589afe9054bfd/log.json: no such file or directory): fork/exec /usr/bin/runc: resource temporarily unavailable: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:

root@h2877818:~# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/04d0e67f08bac10bed19c650868af6bfbc27757584bb096846ed1d8c8602bad8/log.json: no such file or directory): runc did not terminate successfully: exit status 2: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

I don't know why this issue is happening. It's complex because I think it might be related to some limit configuration since the server has enough resources for running the current services and I also have been monitoring the resources' usage with `htop` and the usages are always low.

Right now when I'm typing this we have the issue 3 happening in the server. It's uncertain when this issue is going to stop and when issues 1-3 are going to happen again.